# NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element using Selenium Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests

I am using selenium with Javascript. When I want to click on an element, I am getting this error. I used explicit wait but it did not help. Can anyone help me?

This is test.js file:

```
const Browser = require("../Browser")
const MainPage = require("../pageobjects/MainPage")
const AlertPage = require("../pageobjects/AlertPage");
describe("Test 1", function(){
    it("test case",  async function(){
         await Browser.goToUrl("https://demoqa.com/")
         let mainPage = new MainPage();
         let isMainPageDisplayed = await mainPage.isMainPageDisplayed();
         expect(isMainPageDisplayed).to.be.true
         await mainPage.clickAlertFrameWindows()
         let alertPage = new AlertPage()
         let isAlertPageDisplayed = await alertPage.isAlertElDisplayed();
         expect(isAlertPageDisplayed).to.be.true
         await alertPage.clickAlertEl()
         await Browser.closeBrowser()
    })
})
```

AlertPage.js:

```
class AlertPage{
    #name = "Alert Page";
    #locator = "//span[text()='Alerts']"
    #alertEl = new BaseElement(this.#locator, "Alert button")

    clickAlertEl(){
 BrowserFactory.getBrowser().wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Alerts']/ancestor::li[contains(@class,'btn')]")))
        this.#alertEl.clickWithExecutor()
 
    }
    isAlertElDisplayed(){
        // BrowserFactory.getBrowser().wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Alerts']/ancestor::li[contains(@class,'btn')]")))
        return this.#alertEl.isElementPresent()
    }
}
module.exports = AlertPage;
```

Snapshot of HTML:

[image]`

Comment: You never posted the actual error message. Please edit your question and add the error message as text, properly formatted. Please remove the screenshot of HTML and instead put the relevant HTML as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `<span>` tags are easier to click. So within *`clickAlertEl()`* try:

```
BrowserFactory.getBrowser().wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Alerts']//ancestor::li[1]")))
```

or simply

```
BrowserFactory.getBrowser().wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Alerts']")))
```